# How to display {} as part of python f string

Tags: python, python-3.x, curly-braces, f-string

Is there any way I can display {} as part of the f string as it has special meaning in f string. In other words:

If run `print(f"hello world {}")` , I want a results like `hello world {}`

My attempted solution is: `print(f"hello world \{\}")`. But it did not work.

A help will be much appreciated

Comment: `br = '{}';print(f'hello world {br}')`

Comment: `print(f'Hello world {{}}')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work

```
print(f"hello world {{}}")
```